# Oracle PL/SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in FOR loop

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to do something like the following.

I need a loop for all the IDs from dynamic table,

```
FOR ID_ROW IN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ID FROM ' || SRC_TABLE) LOOP
    -- some SP calling with ID_ROW.ID
END LOOP;
```

It is not working, how can I make it run?

Or if following works then also I can work out a solution,

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ID FROM ' || SRC_TABLE INTO ID_ROW
```

Where ID_ROW would be of type `type CUSTOM_ARRAY is table of VARCHAR2(64);`

Comment: How many rows are you expecting? If that isn't too many, using a `bulk collect` to store all ids in a collection and then iterating over the collection is most probably going to be faster (but it probably won't work with millions of rows)

Comment: It is not working, that's why I have put the question, Please see edited question.

Comment: Won't be millions, but may be hundreds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have collection to be fetched out try this.

```
DECLARE
TYPE num_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
num num_tab;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT NUM  FROM NUMBER_TAB 'BULK COLLECT INTO NUM;
END;
```